# How to add Dispatcher in Background Scheduled Tasks in windows phone application

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Whenever i create a dispatcher is background scheduled task all it says is an error(An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Action)), 
how can i use object of dispatcher here.......
I created an object of System.Windows.Threading but that can't be possible as it is a namespace...

Error Image:
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ffHWrH8vYko/UYyXiKagrUI/AAAAAAAAAN4/PtdqEK5JOPw/s1600/Navjot.png"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In background agents use `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=> ...)` instead to run code on the dispatcher thread.